# SQL wildcard between two strings

Tags: mysql

Suppose you have two tables:

```
            table1                         table2
       id | cityA | cityB              id | cities_queue|
        1     a        c                1    a , b , d
        2     s        f                2    a , b , c ,e
        3     d        m                3    a , m , d , e
```

I want to return only those rows of table 2 that includes cityA and cityB with this specific order, first cityA and after ( somewhere...) comes cityB. 
Because of that the only accepted result must be (a , b , c, e). First thought is to use LIKE command to find which table2 rows include cityA, then using substr() to receive only part of cities_queue that comes after cityA and using LIKE() again for cityB. So my question is: is it possible to use only once LIKE() holding as a string something like

```
 (cityA) - % - (cityB)
```

where  % = wildcard
to find all cities_queue that include cityA and cityB regardless of what is between them; If so, please provide the right syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is your point is but if order of elements has  really important:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83459/7

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.cities_queue LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.cityA,' , ',t1.cityB,'%')
```

or

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.cities_queue LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.cityA,' % ',t1.cityB,'%')
```

Comment: your query works only for the adjacent items, whereas he mentioned that there may be some elements between them

Comment: this code returns every row of table 2 that includes both cityA and cityB at any order. So it returns rows (a,b,c,e) and (a,m,d,e). The second one is not accepted because d must come prior to m

Comment: no. you are wrong. I just added some data into the table. that had never return `(a,m,d,e)` as good record, there was another one **(a,d,m,e)** which is good. So if I got your goal correctly now, I did update\

Comment: second query works fine. first one is wrong IMHO, as it does not return *'a , b , c ,e'* for cities *(a, c)* - which i suppose it should according to the question

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Alex, but I'd go with a [regex](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.cities_queue regexp CONCAT(t1.cityA,'.*',t1.cityB)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83459/3

Comment: did you care to notice, that there is an extra row added in sample data? Suppose you did not - remove it and you'll be just fine... in case you don't know how to use sqlfiddle- i removed that row. updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06f42/1